# Is Synology's QuickConnect secure?

Tags: synology

How does it work? Does it work like a proxy? Will the data being sent and received between my remote computer over the internet and my NAS be secured when using SSL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does it work? Does it work like a proxy?

Yes, a
 Synology server will be the relay server. Your Synology NAS connects to the relay server and your client connects to the relay server and the relay server joins the connections.

This blog post explains it in more detail: [QuickConnect, Quickly Explained (15.11.2013)](http://blog.synology.com/blog/?p=2283)

> Will the data being sent and received between my remote computer over
>   the Internet and my NAS be secured when using SSL?

Yes, it will according to blog post mentioned above. The blog post says that their server only passes the data on without modifying or storing it. Which I interpret as: if your connection between your client and your server are secured by SSL, then the data is secure. QuickConnect doesn't do any encryption. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: Does that mean, if I'm using SSL, there's no way quick connect can obtain my credentials?

Comment: @supertonsky I'd say no. Perhaps, ask your question in the comments section of the linked blog post, or even better, ask him to answer your question over here on Superuser.com. The author working for Synology is very quick with replying. He just answered a question yesterday even though the post is from last year.

Comment: The blog author clarified: "The relay serve [sic] acts as a TCP relay not an SSL relay, whatever data is transfered it’s read, it simply acts as a “passthrough”. Consequently there won’t be any certificate checks between the client and the relay, only between the DS and the client, with the relay serving as a passthough."

Answer (score 4):

Nothing going through an external relay server is secure...they (or another "agency") will capture your packets even though you may not be storing anything on their servers.

Comment: Why no upvotes ? Isn't that true ?

Comment: But per the response above, it is encrypted from Client to the DS.  Hence no middle man.

Comment: That's just means, IF you use ssl connection then the relay server can Not understand your packages, even if it can "capture" or "storing" those packages. To capture and understand what is captured is different thing. Relay server just send packages through "as is".